# How to analyze interdependent variables

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, independence

I have a problem with my research.
I have to analyze the changes of four variables within subjects at different time points (in times) and between subjects in two groups.
The problem is that the 4 variables are interdependent in the sense that their sums, at a certain time point, will always be 100.
I want to know if only one change significantly, or, for instance, 3 of them (says two increases and one decrease) and one remains constant or, again, if one increase respect to the base level in a centrain time point but decrease later on.

What is the best statistical model to deal with this kind of situation?
I don't think that running 4 different RM-ANOVA will be right. The same is probably true for mixed linear models.

Thanks you in advance for all the help.